# How to hide softkeyboard in new Update Oreo 8.1

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, kotlin

How to hide softkeyboard in Oreo 8.1. I'm using this but not working

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: please be more specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use following method You may get your fix.

```
public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (activity.getCurrentFocus() != null && activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken() != null)
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
```